# React why my clearInterval cannot stop setInterval?

Tags: reactjs

I am totally new to React. What I try to implement is a timer. When click on the hours, minute or second the timer will stop and for the selected one turns into an input field when enter button has been click it should not show any more input fields and start back the clock.
[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCdx3.png)

I try to stop passing new props to the child component when I click the flexbox container. I wrote a handleClick function and setInterval() or clearInterval() base on update variable in the state.

**What I want is when I click any of the hour/minute/second, the select filed will change to the input filed, and the timer stop. Once I hit enter it will back to the timer.**

```js
class Timer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super (props);
        this.timerRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            hh: new Date().getHours().toString().padStart(2,"0"),
            mm: new Date().getMinutes().toString().padStart(2,"0"),
            ss: new Date().getSeconds().toString().padStart(2,"0"),
            suffix: new Date().getHours() > 12 ? "PM" : "AM",
            update:true,
        };
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState({
            hh: new Date().getHours().toString().padStart(2,"0"),
            mm: new Date().getMinutes().toString().padStart(2,"0"),
            ss: new Date().getSeconds().toString().padStart(2,"0"),
            suffix: new Date().getHours() > 12 ? "PM" : "AM",
        })
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        this.intervalId = setInterval(
            () => this.tick(), 1000
        );
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }

    handleClick(){       
        this.setState(state => ({update: !state.update}));
        console.log("1",this.state.update);
        if (this.state.update){
            this.intervalId = setInterval(
                () => this.tick(), 1000
            );
            console.log("2 set interval",this.intervalId);
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(this.intervalId);
            console.log("2 clear interval");
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { hh, mm, ss, suffix } = this.state;
        return (
          <div className="box" > London Clock
              <div className="flexbox-container" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
                <Content time={hh}></Content>
                <div><p>:</p></div>
                <Content time={mm}></Content>
                <div><p>:</p></div>
                <Content time={ss}></Content>
                <div className="suffix"><p>{suffix}</p></div>
              </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
    state = {
        editMode: false,
        time: ""
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            time: this.props.time,
        })
    }
    
    
    handleKeyDown(event){
        console.log(event,event.key === 'Enter');
        if (event.key === 'Enter'){
            this.setState({
                editMode: false,
            })
        } 
    }
    
    render() {
        const {editMode} = this.state;
        return (
            <div> 
              {editMode? (
                    <p>
                        <input
                        defaultValue={this.props.time}
                        onKeyPress={e => this.handleKeyDown(e)}
                    />
                    </p>
              ) : (
                    <p onClick={() => this.setState({ editMode: true })}>{this.props.time}</p>
              )}
            </div>
          );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Timer/>,
    document.body
  );
```

```css
.flexbox-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.suffix{
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.box{
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your component is mounted, it will start an interval and assign it to `intervalId`.

Your clickhandler modifies the state and then immediately attemtps to look at the state, without waiting for it to be updated. The state likely is not updated at this point, so it reassigns the interval, resulting in a zombie-updater.

Either pass a callback along to `setState(updater, [callback])` or move your interval-logic to `componentDidUpdate`, which would allow you to de-duplicate interval logic

Comment: Thanks, it is well explained and really make sense. Both methods work for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below instead of setting to state and bind your `tick` function.

```
       componentDidMount(){
            this.intervalId = setInterval(
                () => this.tick.bind(this), 1000
            );
        }
        
        componentWillUnmount(){
            clearInterval(this.intervalId);
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I feel like the problem is in the handleClick function, even tho I can see the program execute the clearInterval inside the handleClick, it still keeps updating the child components.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use React's Ref instead of the state.

```
constructor(props) {
    this.timerRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerRef.current = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerRef.current);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my real problem is I try to clearInterval in handleClick() base on its state and it will not work. The componentDidMount() and componentWillUnmount() looks fine.

Comment: Yeah, you can use this approach in handleClick as well.
I had the same issue in my past project, and resolve the issue in this way.
I think you should store interval id into ref instead of state

Comment: I think use ref works, and @dube is more straightforward for me. Thanks for your answer!